# how to choose which template to show?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have two polymer elements, where one is dependent of the other (like a select and option). So I have a tab element, and a tab area element. I want the tab element to have something like

```
<template name="title-template">

</template>

<template name="content-template">

</template>
```

and the tab area element loads the tab elements (which I have already done), and load each template separately:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <template repeat="{{tab in tabs}}">
            <li>{{tab.getTemplate('title-template')}}</li>
        </template>
    </ul>

    <template repeat="{{tab in tabs}}">
        <div class="tab">
            {{tab.getTemplate('content-template')}}
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Is it possible in polymer? Or should I try to find another approach? If the latter, what can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the templates directly - or am i missing the point ?

```
<polymer-element name="title-element"> 
    <template><content></content></template>
</polymer-element>  

<polymer-element name="tab-element"> 
  <template><content></content></template>
</polymer-element>  

<polymer-element name="tabs-element"> 
<template>
    <title-element></title-element>
    <template repeat="{{tab in tabs}}">
            <tab-element>{{tab}}</tab-element>
    </template>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: My idea was to do an "inheritance" in Polymer. So basically, each polymer element's template would be different. So a "nested" tab will have its title element as a dropdown box while a non nested tab would just have a link. I hope that makes sense.